# SQL Server 2012 - Using ROW_NUMBER() on DISTINCT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    FORMAT(CAST(SchedTi AS DATETIME),'hh:mm tt') AS SchedTimeIn,
    FORMAT(CAST(SchedTO AS DATETIME),'hh:mm tt') AS SchedTimeOut
FROM 
    tblemployee_schedule
ORDER BY 
    SchedTimeIn
```

It returns this resultset:

```
SchedTimeIn  SchedTimeOut
01:00 AM     09:00 AM
01:00 AM     10:00 AM
01:00 AM     10:00 PM
01:15 AM     05:15 AM
01:15 AM     10:15 AM
01:30 AM     05:30 AM
01:30 PM     10:30 PM
01:45 AM     05:45 AM
```

My desired result is:

```
SchedTimeIn  SchedTimeOut ROWNUM
01:00 AM     09:00 AM     1
01:00 AM     10:00 AM     2
01:00 AM     10:00 PM     3
01:15 AM     05:15 AM     4
01:15 AM     10:15 AM     5
01:30 AM     05:30 AM     6
01:30 PM     10:30 PM     7
01:45 AM     05:45 AM     8
```

I tried the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SchedTi),
    FORMAT(CAST(SchedTi AS DATETIME),'hh:mm tt') AS SchedTimeIn,
    FORMAT(CAST(SchedTO AS DATETIME),'hh:mm tt') AS SchedTimeOut
FROM 
    tblemployee_schedule
ORDER BY 
    SchedTimeIn
```

But it returns too many redundant rows and NULL values.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the below one,

```
SELECT * ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY SchedTimeIn) AS ROWNUM
FROM    (
    SELECT DISTINCT
    FORMAT(CAST(SchedTi AS DATETIME),'hh:mm tt') AS SchedTimeIn,
    FORMAT(CAST(SchedTO AS DATETIME),'hh:mm tt') AS SchedTimeOut
    FROM tblemployee_schedule
)   AS  D
ORDER BY ROWNUM
```

In your query `ROW_NUMBER()` produce a new sequence number for each records , so the `DISTINCT` key will not wok for the same, that's why you are getting too many redundant records. So you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` in an outer query to overcome this.

Comment: Why? What did you change, and why did you change it? This reads like a game of spot-the-difference, not an answer.

Comment: Big thanks to you sir!

Answer (score 1):

Main problem is you are asking only part of problem,
In firstplace using distinct,order by,row_number in same query seem wrong.
using only partition function is enough.

any way using your query,

```
select * 
,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by SchedTimeIn)rn
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT
FORMAT(CAST(SchedTi AS DATETIME),'hh:mm tt') AS SchedTimeIn,
FORMAT(CAST(SchedTO AS DATETIME),'hh:mm tt') AS SchedTimeOut
FROM tblemployee_schedule
ORDER BY SchedTimeIn
)tbl
```